# Drawer layout class not found error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, gradle

I updated my minSDKVersion from 19 to 21. When I try running my app it crashes now. I get "Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didnt find class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" any idea how to fix this?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.id"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

repositories {

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'


}
```

Comment: please try an update from 19.1.0 to something else like com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.0 and let us know if it did the trick after cleaning the project

Comment: @PopTudor-it doesnt work. I added  com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.0 and now i  get a "Cant resolve symbol 'DrawerLayout' in my main activity

Comment: try this compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'

Comment: @PopTudor- Nope still get the same error

Comment: did you try to rebuild the project ? Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: @PopTudor-Yes, I did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122236/discussion-between-pop-tudor-and-amanda45).

Comment: @PopTudor- no matter what I try i get the same error. IF I change the minSDK back to 19 it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have updated your sdk with project change : import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle; remove import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;